# Have A File Download Link/Button Also Update A MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, download

I have a download button on a form that updates a MySQL database, and updates the number of downloads/the download count of a file. I thought I'd be able to add the `download` attribute to this form button and provide the url to the file so the file would also download. It seems you can only use the `download` attribute on anchor `<a>` links. That in itself isn't an issue, I can just style the anchor link like I have the button - but how can I get it so when someone clicks the `<a>` link, as well as downloading the image, it also submits data to the database?

**Simplified version of form button that submits to MySQL database:**

```
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="download">Download</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?php echo $image_filename; ?>">
</form>
```

**A 'download' file link:**

```
<a download href="localhost/project/image/file.jpg">Download</a>
```

I've also included the PHP function that updates the database for reference purposes. This function is called on the page itself where the images are downloaded. Note: `$connection` is the database connection code that is imported at the top of the functions.php file where this function is.

**PHP**

```
function downloadCounter($connection, $filename) {
    if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
        // value from a hidden form element which outputs the filename
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];

        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE lj_imageposts SET downloads = downloads +1 WHERE filename = :filename";
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->execute([
                ':filename' => $filename
            ]);


        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle both operations in a JS function. First you need to update the DB, then download the file

```
const downloadFile = element => {
   const downloadLink = element.getAttribute("href"); //Get element's href value
   const updateURL = "example.com/update"; //Your server side file to update db
   fetch(updateURL {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: `downloadLink=${downloadLink}`
   })
   .then(result = > {
      //If successful, download the file
      location.href = downloadLink;
   })
   .catch(error = > {
      //Handle the error
   });
};
```

And your `a` tag

```
<a onclick="downloadFile(this)" href="localhost/project/image/file.jpg">Download</a>
```